# Suitable Java Binary not found

Tags: 14.04, java

I installed OMEGAT and while trying to run the application from terminal following error was displayed:`Suitable Java Binary was not found.`
Where is java binary located and how am I suppose to troubleshoot?

Comment: Most likely issues are: You don't have java installed; you have it installed but not on your PATH; you don't have the right version installed for the software. To test them type `java -version` into a terminal and then confirm that that version is the version required by the software

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Java installed. To install oracle java do the following.

Install manually:

Download the right java-version for your os's archtecture from here:

[java for linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Make sure you take the .tar.gz-archive and unpack it to /usr/bin/java. You can do the same with the jre provided in the link above.

Then set the path-variable by opening the shell and typing this chant:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/substitute_this_with_your_java_version/ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Install via ppa:

Add this ppa to your sources.list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Now follow the installer. It will set path automagically.

Both methods can be checked:

```
java -version
```

should throw something similar to this depending on your java version

```
java version "1.8.0_31" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

javac -version
```

should throw something similar to this also depending on the version you have installed.

```
javac 1.8.0_31
```

-Cheers-

Techmod